# Xamarin Forms project How to target .NET Framework4.6

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I have a Xamarin.Forms project with its pcl targets .netframework4.5

I want to use a nuget package written with .netframework4.6. How can I do it?

I tried to convert my existing pcl project to a .netStandard project, however it didn't work as I multitarget both .netStandart and .netFramework.

Then I tried to convert the .netStandart classLibrary Project to a project that targets only .netFramework4.6 and reference it from my pcl project. I couldn't reference it neither from my pcl nor from my .droid project as .netFramework4.6 is not supported.

I am developing an Android app, therefore it is enough for me to find a solution that works only for Android.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortinalty, you can't change it to 4.6. The thing is that Xamarin uses a special profile to work with .NET Frameworks 4.5. It's custom configured to work with mobile devices. So untill Xamarin (now Microsoft) came out with a new profile for Xamarin that tartget .NET Framework 4.6, you can't change the version of it.

Comment: I understand that I can't use .NET4.6 in a Xamarin Forms PCL project, but as far as I understand, this guy claims we can accomplish it by converting PCL to a .NET Standard project. [link](https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2017/10/17/targeting-net-standard-xamarin-forms-shared-libraries/)